# label timestamps by intervals in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk to split a file where I have three splits separated by spaces: 1. starting point; 2. ending point; 3. label

I want to create new labels within defined frames which requires an if which is where I am a little stuck.

I am looking for something like this:

```
num_intervals == (tail -1 | ending point)/250000
count == 1
interval == 2500000
current_interval_start == 0
current_interval_end == current_interval_start + interval
for interval in num_intervals
    if starting_point >= current_interval_start and if ending_point <= current_interval_end then
        print count + label
        count == count + 1
        current_interval_start == current_interval_end
        current_interval_end == current_interval_start + interval
```

*observation if two labels are in the same interval range, take the first one, but I could post process this.

My data looks like this:

```
0 2300000 null
2300000 4300000 h
4300000 8000000 aa
8000000 11500000 t
11500000 28400001 null
```

What I would like as output would be this:

```
0 2500000 null
2500000 5000000 h
5000000 7500000 aa
7500000 1000000 aa
1000000 1250000 t
1250000 1500000 null
1500000 1750000 null
1750000 2000000 null
2000000 2250000 null
2500000 2750000 null
2750000 3000000 null
```

Comment: You want to round all the current numbers up to the nearest number evenly divisible by `2500000` and then chunk up each range into units of that size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with only awk:

```
 awk  -v s=2500000 '{
    f=int($1/s);
    l=int($2/s);
    if((l-f) > 0){
         for(i=f+1;i<=l;i++){
               a[i]=$3
         }
    }
}
END {
    e=int($2/s);
    for (i=0;i<=e;i++){
         if (i in a ){
              print i*s,(i+1)*s,a[i]
         }
         else{
              print i*s,(i+1)*s,"null"
         }
    }
}'
```

Comment: that is steller!  took me a little bit of playing with it to understand exactly what it was doing but it is exactly what I was trying to do!  Thanks!